# Probability of hitting a quad when the flop has a three of a kind in Texas Hold'em

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poker

Let's assume that I am playing Texas Hold'em with 5 of my friends (total 6 players). I have pockets Kings (KK). Now the flop has 3 A (AAA). I want to figure out if anyone on the board has beaten me after the flop. What would be the probability of me getting beaten?

I think the only way to beat me would be to have the final A. What would be the probability of anyone else in the game have that A?

Comment: That last Ace would have to _miss_ being dealt into your friends' hands.  How many times would it have to miss?

Comment: Is it 46/ 47? In that case, the answer would be 1/47, right?

Comment: Annoyingly, you can't eliminate the (tiny) possibility of someone getting a straight flush (either a royal flush or a steel wheel), so winning is not *quite* as simple as nobody else having the fourth ace.

Comment: I am thinking about beating me after the flop. In that case, isn't the quad the only possible solution?

Comment: If you had, say, the ace of hearts in the flop, then the king of hearts in the river, and the queen of hearts in the turn, and one of your opponents had the jack and 10 of hearts in their hands, then this would be a royal flush, beating your full house.

Comment: But that requires the inclusion of turn and river, right? I was just hoping to compute the probability of getting beaten after the flop. An extension can be done when I will try to figure the probability of getting beaten after the 5 cards

Comment: As in, you want to compute the probability of winning after, against all rules of Texas Hold 'em, you and your opponents decide to show all of your hands after the flop is down, and figure out who has the best poker hand without the turn or the river? Then sure, an ace in someone else's hand is the only way for you to be beaten.

Comment: Sure, why not. What would be the probability then? My understanding is the answer is 1/47. But I am not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the probability of one of your friends holding the last ace, we need to find the number of ways that one of them can have the ace and divide this by the total number of ways the remaining $47$ cards can be arranged. A simple way to do this would to consider those $47$ cards to be in a single deck, where the bottom $5$ pairs ($10$ cards) represent your friends' hands. The total number of ways the cards can be arranged in this deck is $47!$, and the number of arrangements with the ace in the bottom $10$ cards is $10*46!$ ($10$ possible positions for the ace and $46!$ possible arrangements of the other $46$ cards). Therefore, the probability of one of your friends holding the ace is
$$\frac{10*46!}{47!} = \frac{10*46!}{47*46!} = \frac{10}{47}$$

Comment: It is interesting to note that by [brute force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) the pair of Kings get beaten around $21.45\%$ of the time, which is more than $\frac{10}{47}$ due to turn and river cards.